# How to login a large number of users in Jmeter?

Tags: performance, testing, automation, jmeter, automated-tests

I have a project and need to test a large number of of users in Jmeter but the problem  I am facing is how to login lots of users, it will be tedious for me to enter their data manually and the token.

Can we remove or bypass the session id/token? So I won't need to input it manually. Is there any simple way to login lacks of user so I can test the load and stress testing. Or is there any other open source tool in which I test this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read the [Apache JMeter User Manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/) first.

You work around to be like:

1. Try to record only one user login session using the [Apache JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf).
2. Use [CSV Dataset Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to pass all your login credentials in JMeter.
3. Add a [Cookie manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) in your test plan.
4. Use regular expression extractor or JSON path processor (Depending on your request type) if you need bypass any data in your subsequent request. Check this [article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations).
5. You won't be able to simulate one lack users from your machine I guess.Actually, it depends on your hardware configuration. So check for the [Distributed testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf).
6. You have run your test in Non-GUI mode. You can use GUI mode for the only debugging purpose.
7. Do not add any listeners when you perform your load test since they consume more memory.
8. Try to tweak your JDK heap size accordingly.
9. Try to use updated JMeter version and JDK both.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on your application design, for instance if usernames are matching some pattern like:

```
user1
user2
user3
etc.
```

you should be able to just add [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function as a postfix

If your users are present in a database table you can use [JDBC Test Elements](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mysql-database-and-jmeter-how-to-test-your-connection) to read usernames from the database

When it comes to logging in, it is not about single request which performs login operation, your web application test must always represent real users using real browsers as close as possible, so the login flow should look like:

- Open Login Page

  - Extract token using one of JMeter [Post Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)
- Perform login providing credentials and the token from the previous step

More information:

- [Building a Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html)
- [Building an Advanced Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-adv-web-test-plan.html)
- [How To Login Into A Web Application with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/jmeter-training/how-login-web-application-jmeter)